# How to generate text area dynamically in web designing

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

How to generate text area dynamically using jsp ?

```
Ex - <textarea rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
```

Or how can i generate it on a button click, on a link in the same page ?

Comment: Please post what you have done already and your Basic html structur

Comment: Thanks for your responses ,i have done this by innerHTML ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function hello()
{
txtsarea=document.createElement("textarea");
txtsarea.rows='20'
txtsarea.columns='40'
document.body.appendChild(txtsarea);
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY> 
india <input type='checkbox' id='chk' onclick='hello()'>
</BODY>
```